# Where can I find an English translation of Vaimānika Shāstra?

Tags: scripture

According to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaim%C4%81nika_Sh%C4%81stra), there is scripture called Vaimanika Shastra. Where can I find it's original book and it's english translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [an](https://archive.org/details/vimanikashastravimanajoyserg.r._32_b/page/25/mode/1up) english version translated by G.R. Josyer.